# STM32F4 PWM input mode with DMA. Cannot measure duty cycle

Tags: c, arm, stm32f4discovery

I am trying to measure PWM signal duty cycle. I strive to make all configurations in STM32CubeMX and also I am using STM32F407G-Disc1 discovery board.

I have configured one timer to generate PWM signal and another to capture it.

TIM2 below is used to generate PWM signal with cycle time (T) of 20ms and Ton = 1ms.
[image: TIM2 generating PWM signal]

TIM3 is configured in PWM input capture mode. Currently I doubt proper configuration. Can you please verify that first?

[image: Pin configuration of the TIM3]
[image: TIM3 PWM input capture mode]

Then I have wire connected from `PA0 (TIM2_CH1)` to `PA6 (TIM3_CH1)`, also there an LED connected to visually verify the signal. It was also checked with an oscilloscope - pwm is generated correctly.

---

Next step was to capture measured values with DMA requests.

**autogenerated main.c**

```
uint32_t pwm[1] = {0};
// ...
if(HAL_TIM_IC_Start_DMA(&htim3, TIM_CHANNEL_1, pwm, 1) != HAL_OK)
{
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
}
```

Debugging later shows contents of `pwm[0]` equal to `20000` which is correct.

How would I measure Ton (when signal is logical 1) of the cycle?

I have tried enabling DMA request for the channel 2 of TIM3 as well, but it ends up in `_Error_Handler()`.

---

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post the DMA configuration code?